# ERROR WITH 'LIKE' IN MULITPLE WHERE MYSQL STATEMENT

Tags: mysql, sql-like

```
SELECT surplusland_list.*,site_file_sets.*,demandstar.identifier, demandstar.date_due
FROM surplusland_list,site_file_sets,demandstar
WHERE surplusland_list.its_number != 'NULL' AND 
      surplusland_list.its_number = demandstar.identifier AND
      site_file_sts.name LIKE %{demandstar.identifier}%
ORDER BY surplusland_list.county ASC, surplusland_list.assoc_property ASC, surplusland_list.id ASC
```

How can I correct this statement? I have an error at the `%{demandstar.identifier}%`. I have tried many different versions of this statment and cant seem to get it to work. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your statement has multiple problems.  First, you should learn and use proper `join` syntax and realize that table aliases will simplify the query.  That will show that you have no join condition for `site_file_sets`, which this is showing as a `cross join`.

```
SELECT sl.*, sfs.*, ds.identifier, ds.date_due
FROM surplusland_list sl join
     demandstart ds
     on sl.its_number = ds.identifier cross join
     site_file_sets sfs
WHERE sl.its_number != 'NULL' AND 
      sfs.name LIKE %{demandstar.identifier}%
ORDER BY sl.county ASC, sl.assoc_property ASC, sl.id ASC;
```

The next two problems are the lack of single quote around the `like` pattern, and the `!= NULL`.  The `!= NULL` will always return `NULL` which is treated as false.  This is the improved version:

```
SELECT sl.*, sfs.*, ds.identifier, ds.date_due
FROM surplusland_list sl join
     demandstart ds
     on sl.its_number = ds.identifier cross join
     site_file_sets sfs
WHERE sl.its_number is not 'NULL' AND 
      sfs.name LIKE '%{demandstar.identifier}%'
ORDER BY sl.county ASC, sl.assoc_property ASC, sl.id ASC;
```

However, this will not do what you want until you replace the `cross join` with an appropriate `join` and `on` clause.

Answer (score 1):

The argument to `LIKE` is a string, and should be properly quoted.

Try `LIKE '%{demandstar.identifier}%'`